# How to install PNGOUT on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions, 18.04, png

I am following steps outlined in a document. The document was probably written for `16.04` or earlier release.

When I execute the instruction with `sudo` command prepended, I get an error:

`cp: cannot create regular file '/bin/pngout': Permission denied`

The command is:

```
wget http://static.jonof.id.au/dl/kenutils/pngout-20150319-linux.tar.gz \
  && tar -xf pngout-20150319-linux.tar.gz \
  && rm pngout-20150319-linux.tar.gz \
  && cp pngout-20150319-linux/x86_64/pngout /bin/pngout \
  && rm -rf pngout-20150319-linuxwget http://static.jonof.id.au/dl/kenutils/pngout-20150319-linux.tar.gz \
  && tar -xf pngout-20150319-linux.tar.gz \
  && rm pngout-20150319-linux.tar.gz \
  && cp pngout-20150319-linux/x86_64/pngout /bin/pngout \
  && rm -rf pngout-20150319-linux
```

Comment: *"When I execute the instruction with sudo command prepended"* That's actually 9 separate commands - just prepending `sudo`before `wget` (if that's what you did) won't give elevated permissions to `cp`

Comment: ah, thank you, that was helpful & resolved that particular issue.